# Push navigation transition remove shadow

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I found that Flutter App has slightly hard shadows than the Native App when pushing a new screen.

I searched on the internet and I didn't find much about this. Is there any way to remove that shadow?

[image: Flutter App]

[image: Native App]

### Flutter doctor

[image: Flutter doctor]

### Full reproducible code

File: `main.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: Center(child: CupertinoButton(child: Text('Navigate'), onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'details'))),
    );
  }
}

class Details extends StatefulWidget {
  Details({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DetailsState createState() => _DetailsState();
}

class _DetailsState extends State<Details> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: Center(child: Text('Details')),
    );
  }
}

Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  switch (settings.name) {
    case '/':
      return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home());

    case 'details':
      return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => Details());

    default:
      return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home());
  }
}
```